# Splitting large multi class dataset using leave one out scheme into train and test

Tags: python, neural-network, scikit-learn, cross-validation, numpy

I am doing some supervised learning using neural networks, and i have a Targets array containing 1906 samples, which contain 664 unique values. min. count of each unique value==2, by design. Is there a smarter way to split this dataset into train and test, using a leaveoneout scheme to pick randomly 1 sample from each class and put it in the test set and use the rest for training, before i get down to explicitly iterating over all my values? I am using python, numpy, sklearn and pytorch btw!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind! Found it!

just doing `a,indices,counts=np.unique(y)` will return the starting indices of each unique value in `indices`, and then you can just slice this off as `x_test=X[indices]`, and remember to delete it using `np.delete(X,indices)`